# What is the best way to reuse a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, I need to reuse a same divider more than 20 times.

Which way should I follow for best memory performance?

**Way 1:**

```dart
class DividerX extends StatelessWidget { 
  const DividerX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Divider(color: Colors.green, height: 22); 
  }
}
```

**Way 2:**

```
class DividerX { 
  const DividerX._();

  static const Widget divider = Divider(color: Colors.green, height: 22); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one. From [Dart's website](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html):

> Const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable. (...)  [Const objects] are *canonicalized*. This is sort of like string interning: for any given const value, a single const object will be created and re-used no matter how many times the const expression(s) are evaluated.